# Unexpected error of logic

Tags: perl, file, file-io, logic

I'm trying to write a perl script which will read a file line by line, compare a particular substring of each line with that of the previously read line, and if different, writes it to a new file. In effect, script removes non-unique lines among sequential lines of a file.

The script seems to be suffering from a logical error, as instead of getting unique lines in the output file, I just get the terminating line.

```
use strict;
my $src='/var/www/pinginfo/ugvps';
my $tar="target";
open(INP, $src) or die("Could not open: $!.");
open(OUTP, ">", $tar) or die "Couldn't open: $!";
my $lastrd="";
while( my $line = <INP> ) {
    if ( &IsSame($lastrd, $line)) {
        print "Unique line: ".$line."\n";
        print OUTP $line;
        $lastrd=$line;
    } else {
        print "Line was the same: ".$line."\n";
    }
}
print OUTP "Done";
close (OUTP);
close (INP);
exit 0;

sub IsSame {
    my $old=$_[0];
    my $new=$_[1];
    if ( $old == "" ) {
        return 0;
    }
    my @values_old = split('\|',$old);
    my @values_new = split('\|',$new);
    if ( $values_old[3] eq $values_new[3] ) {
        #True - they are the same
        return 1;
    } else {
        #False
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The file 'target' after execution, contains the single line `Done`.

My source file looks like this:

```
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 10:16:21 PM|0
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:06:01 PM|0
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:08:01 PM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:10:01 PM|0
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:14:01 PM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:16:01 PM|0
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:52:02 PM|0
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:54:01 PM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:56:01 PM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:58:01 PM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:00:01 AM|0
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:02:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:04:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:06:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:08:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:10:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:12:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:14:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:16:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:18:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:20:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:22:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:24:01 AM|0
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 02:38:01 AM|0
```

Comment: All lines are different. A big error I can see (there could be more) is the comparison using numeric operator (`!=`). `Perl` uses `ne` for it.

Comment: I corrected the operator. Unfortunately the error remains.

Comment: ` if ( $old == "" ) ` is also a numeric comparison and as an empty String (`""`) is false too you could simply say `if($old)`

Comment: +1 for this really well-formulated question. It shows the full source code, provides the input data, allows the answerers to reproduce the problem on their own, and keeps speculation of the cause separate from the observation of the symptoms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok, I did it:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $src='./input.txt';
my $tar="./target.txt";
open(INP, $src) or die("Could not open: $!.");
open(OUTP, ">", $tar) or die "Couldn't open: $!";
my $lastrd="";
while( my $line = <INP> ) {
    unless ( IsSame($lastrd, $line)) {
        print "Unique line: ".$line."\n";
        print OUTP $line;
        $lastrd=$line;
    } else {
        print "Line was the same: ".$line."\n";
    }
}
print OUTP "Done";
close (OUTP);
close (INP);
exit 0;

sub IsSame {
    my $old=$_[0];
    my $new=$_[1];
    if ( $old eq "" ) {
        return 0;
    }
    my @values_old = split('\|',$old);
    my @values_new = split('\|',$new);
    if ( $values_old[3] eq $values_new[3] ) {
        #True - they are the same
        return 1;
    } else {
        #False
        return 0;
    }
}
```

prints:

```
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 10:16:21 PM|0
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:08:01 PM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:10:01 PM|0
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:14:01 PM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:16:01 PM|0
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|03-08-2013 11:54:01 PM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:00:01 AM|0
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:02:01 AM|100
UGVPS|6.6.6.6|04-08-2013 12:24:01 AM|0
Done
```

If you enabled warnings in your code, you could see useful information:

```
Argument "" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at 7.pl line 28, <INP> line 2.
Argument "" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at 7.pl line 28, <INP> line 3.
```

Which could help you to find `==` bug.

Also I changed `if ( &IsSame($lastrd, $line))` to `unless ( IsSame($lastrd, $line))`

Comment: I guess the OP does much shell programming, because either use `==` and `!=` to compare strings and `return 0` for success are the reverse in `perl`.